# How to recognize a cell of table, which has been clicked?

Tags: angularjs, draggable, tabular

I am trying to make something like this on following picture.

[image]

I want to make a table, which looks like a calendar. Also I want make cells clickable and I want to know, which cell was clicked. Probably a HTML5 attribute data-* will be useful for it.
It would be best if it could be "draggable", I mean if it would be possible to select more cells by drag of mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass your model object or the item in the collection you are looping into your `ng-click` event method.

Let's say you loop through a collection to render the cells

```
<div ng-repeat="day in calendarDays">
  <a href="#" ng-click="dayClicked(day)">
     Show some markup here as needed
  </a>
</div>
```

Assuming `calendarDays` is an array / collection in your `$scope` and `dayClicked` is a method in your `$scope` which accepts a data structure which represents a day item.